# Ionic 4 / Angular: HTTP Post send Body as text/plain always form-url-encoded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-httpclient, ionic-native

I am building an Ionic 4 Application for Android and iOS and debugging it in the browser, using the devapp on iOS.

I would like to pass data to an external API, which has no CORS-Headers set.
I can not change the API, which expects the body data to be a plain text.

I tried using { **HttpClient**} from '@angular/common/http' and setting the Content-Type Header manually to text/plain. This results in a CORS-Error in the browser, while in the Devapp, the request works as intended but the body is form-url-encoded so the data can not be processed by the API.

Another thing I tried was using { **HTTP** } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx' and setting the serializer to `utf8`, which should not encode the body. It does, at least in the devapp. When using the browserI get another CORS-Error but the Data is not encoded.

At last I tried using https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend which brings me the same results I already got.

#### MyPage.page.ts

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

***

constructor(public userData: UserData, public alertController: AlertController, private http: HTTP, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

***
   const req = 'ABC - The Data; Not Encoded';

//Angular/Common/http
//removing the headers results in the same result.
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'text/plain',
        'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
      }),
      observe: 'response' as 'body'
    };
    this.httpClient.post(url, req, httpOptions).subscribe(async data => {
      console.log("nice");
      console.log(data);
      }
    }, async  err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

//Ionic-Native/HTTP
//removing the headers results in the same result.
    this.http.setDataSerializer('utf8');
    this.http.post(url, req, {'content-type': 'text/plain'} ).then(data => {
       console.log("yeah");
       console.log(data);
     }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
    });
```

On Server side:

Expected: `ABC - The Data; Not Encoded`

Got: `=ABC%20-%20The%20Data%3B%20Not%20Encoded`

Comment: I don't think you can set request headers that way (in the Angular HttpClient). Have you tried using `HttpHeaders`?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Comment: Yes, i tried using HttpHeaders.When using Ionic-Native/http the devapp just crashes, when using Angular/common/http the result is `ABC%20-%20The%20Data%3B%20Not%20Encoded=` and the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded again. So the headers worked before (I also saw that the headers were set)